# Reorder bootstrap columns by data-attribute

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, custom-data-attribute

I have a list of checked-in people and I'm outputting them in 2-cols width columns. That means I have six entries for each row. The data is fetched out of a database and is ordered by check in date and time.

As soon as I have that list I want to reorder it by a (for example) data-attribute. This attribute has values from 0-15 and I want to reorder it descending. The problem is, I can set that data-attribute not at first, I have to select the checked-in people first, then I can set the data-attribute.

I have read about the push and pull classes for bootstrap. Is this the way to go?

Comment: Please create a reproducible example.

Comment: I have created this fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/t5348vp8/ I want to order the columns by the data-order attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the push/pull classes would get confusing. Why not just sort the DIV columns using jQuery:

```
  var columns = $('[data-order]');
  columns.sort(function(a, b){
      return $(a).data("order")-$(b).data("order")
  });

  $("#list").html(columns);
```

http://bootply.com/NppP4pEetz